# C++ : why have a return in a if statement?

Tags: c++, arduino

I've trying to work out why someone would write the following section of code in a Arduino loop.  To me, it doesnt make sense, why have a return in a if statement?  Does it just return to the start of the loop and not carry on with the rest of the loop. Here's the snippet of interest:

```
  if (!modem.available()) {
    Serial.println("No downlink message received at this time.");
    return;
  }
```

Here's the full code

```
/*
  Lora Send And Receive
  This sketch demonstrates how to send and receive data with the MKR WAN 1300/1310 LoRa module.
  This example code is in the public domain.
*/

#include <MKRWAN.h>

LoRaModem modem;

// Uncomment if using the Murata chip as a module
// LoRaModem modem(Serial1);

#include "arduino_secrets.h"
// Please enter your sensitive data in the Secret tab or arduino_secrets.h
String appEui = SECRET_APP_EUI;
String appKey = SECRET_APP_KEY;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);
  // change this to your regional band (eg. US915, AS923, ...)
  if (!modem.begin(EU868)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to start module");
    while (1) {}
  };
  Serial.print("Your module version is: ");
  Serial.println(modem.version());
  Serial.print("Your device EUI is: ");
  Serial.println(modem.deviceEUI());

  int connected = modem.joinOTAA(appEui, appKey);
  if (!connected) {
    Serial.println("Something went wrong; are you indoor? Move near a window and retry");
    while (1) {}
  }

  // Set poll interval to 60 secs.
  modem.minPollInterval(60);
  // NOTE: independent of this setting, the modem will
  // not allow sending more than one message every 2 minutes,
  // this is enforced by firmware and can not be changed.
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Enter a message to send to network");
  Serial.println("(make sure that end-of-line 'NL' is enabled)");

  while (!Serial.available());
  String msg = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Sending: " + msg + " - ");
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
    Serial.print(msg[i] >> 4, HEX);
    Serial.print(msg[i] & 0xF, HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();

  int err;
  modem.beginPacket();
  modem.print(msg);
  err = modem.endPacket(true);
  if (err > 0) {
    Serial.println("Message sent correctly!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error sending message :(");
    Serial.println("(you may send a limited amount of messages per minute, depending on the signal strength");
    Serial.println("it may vary from 1 message every couple of seconds to 1 message every minute)");
  }
  delay(1000);
  if (!modem.available()) {
    Serial.println("No downlink message received at this time.");
    return;
  }
  char rcv[64];
  int i = 0;
  while (modem.available()) {
    rcv[i++] = (char)modem.read();
  }
  Serial.print("Received: ");
  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    Serial.print(rcv[j] >> 4, HEX);
    Serial.print(rcv[j] & 0xF, HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: "Does it just return to the start of the loop and not carry on with the rest of the loop" - yes exactly. And if that's what you need to do, that's a simple way to do it.

Comment: @Mat I think you are mixed up with `continue`.  `return` exits the function.

Comment: @NathanOliver: `loop()` in Arduino code gets called in a loop. Returning from it just restarts the function. Toplevel code of the framework is essentially `setup(); while (1) {loop();}`

Comment: @Mat Oh, neat.  I'll have to remember that.

Comment: Is it good practice?   It through me off because I was expecting the code to continue.  Would it be better to create a Boolean variable and create a if statement to test the Boolean if i wanted to run the code, that's my personal method.  Interested in knowing opinions.

Comment: the `while (1) {}` look more worrying, unless thats also an arduino thingy

Comment: @resolver101 Early return to exit a function is a very common and understandable pattern. Using an extra boolean flag, and additional branches clutters the code and can make it harder to read.

Comment: *Is it good practice?* IMHO, yes.  I hate using variables to keep track of exit conditions.  It doesn't scale well.  Just returning makes it clear if you've reached here, the function is going to end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being able to `return` from functions early is one major reason to use functions. Arduino perculiarities aside, a very common case is for example to break out of nested loops. Suppose you have

```
for (int i = 0; i < imax; ++i) {
     for (int j = 0; j < jmax; ++j) {
         do_something(i,j);
         if (some_condition(i,j)) {
             // now I want to break out of both loops...
         }
     }
}
```

`break` only breaks the inner most loop. If you want to break out of more than one nested loop you can introduce `bool` flags and make them part of the loop conditions, though this ends in a mess rather fast. Usually the much cleaner way is to place the loops in a function and simply `return` from the function:

```
void my_nested_loops() {
    for (int i = 0; i < imax; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < jmax; ++j) {
            do_something(i,j);
            if (some_condition(i,j)) {
               return; // breaks out of both loops
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In some sense your code is an inside out variant of this. The `loop` function is called for you in a loop and because the loop is not in your control, you cannot use `continue` to continue with the next loop iteration, but you can call `return`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  Just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

After `return <value>;` or just `return;` (for void functions) the program exits from the loop and also from function. The function returns `<value>` (for non-void functions). This statement applies when executing function already is not requeris.

Answer (score 0):

simple return; in void function is used to "break" function. When you don't want to execute rest of it program just will return in stack to function what called executing function.